# DOB in select rounded to year

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, procedure, date

I have procedure

```
create procedure sp_ChildrenOlderThan5Years
as
select clientid,firstName,MidInitial, LastName, address, city, 'AK' as 'State', zip,DATEDIFF(YEAR,dob,GETDATE()) as age
from Clients
where CategCode = 'CH' and StatusID in (1,2,6) and DATEDIFF(YEAR,dob,GETDATE())>6
go
```

which must show me clients older than 6 years . However i just found out it is round they ages for example if client was born on 07/20/2007, it still show this client in list however he or she is not six. I know problem in `DATEDIFF(YEAR,dob,GETDATE())`, but  do not know how to fix.
I need client only who is older or equal 5 years and 10 months listed in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are seeking those older than 5 years and 10 months (or equal), use:

```
 datediff(month,dob,getdate()) >= 70
```

Comment: but how to show exact there age for example 5.8 in select `DATEDIFF(YEAR,dob,GETDATE()) as age` because it shows me that all of them is 6 years :)

Comment: DateDiff will always return an integer.  YOu could divide the datediff(month,dob,getdate()) by 12 to get 5.8

Comment: Thanx!! it is still shows integer but its ok :) at least its shows if they are 6 years or 5 :)